# Need to safely remove corrupted file from GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

At our company we have a custom GitLab set up, hosted locally, that was set up by a person no longer with the company. We never had any problems until we had a file created by a developer with the name `<div class="contain pr">`. We use Source Tree to interface with Git, and this file name now causes Source Tree to crash as soon as anyone makes this particular repository active. I need to remove the bad file name from history completed. I also need to make a backup of all necessary parts of Git and GitLab in case I mess this up. I am not comfortable in command line but I suspect this is where I have to go. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git filter-branch --tree-filter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History):

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mv "<div class=\"contain pr\">" some_safe_name ||:' <all branches where the problematic files exists>
```

You may avoid creating the file in the file system with `git filter-branch --index-filter`, thus, the following command can be run even in MS Windows:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached "<div class=\"contain pr\">"  ||:' master
```

but beware, this command simply removes the "bad" file from the tree in the whole `master` branch. If you need to preserve its content (do you?), then you have to use a script invoking `git ls-files -s` and `git update-index`.

You may rewrite all branches, it's safe, the branches without the "bad" file will not be affected. However, with the precise specification of branches the transformation will be faster, this could be important for a large repository, especially in MS Windows.

After the operation is completed you could inspect the results, and if everything is Ok, you may remove original references with
`rm -rf .git/refs/original`.

In case of any problem you always can restart from the beginning, by moving the original references in `.git/refs/original` over their counterparts in `.git/refs/heads`, and `.git/refs/remotes`.

If you have any signed tags affected by the change, probably, they need to be recreated after the change.

Also, you need to ask all your colleagues to re-fetch the entire repository after the transformation is complete and original references are completely removed.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I was able to get to the problematic branch in the terminal and run the command you provided. However, when it reached the given commits it gave the following error: 'error: Invalid path <div class="contain pr">'.

Comment: Do you perform the command on a Unix-like system, (Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris etc)? On those systems it's possible to have a file with such a name in the filesystem. And I had checked the solution before I posted this answer.

Comment: Alternatively you could use index-filter but perhaps the solution would be slightly more complex, I'm preparing the example right now...

Comment: Do you need to preserve the content of the broken file, or it could be safely removed?

Comment: I am working on a Windows machine. I do not need to preserve the content of the file. The problem manifests differently on our macs, still causing problems, but only causing crashes on the Windows machines. For now I have created a separate development branch to work on.

Comment: You may clean your repository with `git filter-branch --index-filter...` described above